# Detect Link or URL in ASTextNode AsyncDisplayKit

Tags: ios, uitextview, asyncdisplaykit

I been trying to use `AsyncDisplayKit` framework , I have an requirement to detect url's in text.

I have used `ASTextNode` but couldn't find any api to detect links.

I read that there is property `linkAttributeNames` used for url detection but unable to find any example how to do it.

Could someone help me how to use the above class?

thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For Swift 3.0

```
func addLinkDetection(_ text: String, highLightColor: UIColor, delegate: ASTextNodeDelegate) {
    self.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    self.delegate = delegate

    let types: NSTextCheckingResult.CheckingType = [.link]
    let detector = try? NSDataDetector(types: types.rawValue)
    let range = NSMakeRange(0, text.characters.count)
    if let attributedText = self.attributedText {
        let mutableString = NSMutableAttributedString()
        mutableString.append(attributedText)
        detector?.enumerateMatches(in: text, range: range) {
            (result, _, _) in
            if let fixedRange = result?.range {
                mutableString.addAttribute(NSUnderlineColorAttributeName, value: highLightColor, range: fixedRange)
                mutableString.addAttribute(NSLinkAttributeName, value: result?.url, range: fixedRange)
                mutableString.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: highLightColor, range: fixedRange)

            }
        }
        self.attributedText = mutableString
    }        
}
```

Add the delegate to your viewController:

```
/// Delegate function for linkDetection
func textNode(_ textNode: ASTextNode, shouldHighlightLinkAttribute attribute: String, value: Any, at point: CGPoint) -> Bool {
    return true
}

func textNode(_ textNode: ASTextNode, tappedLinkAttribute attribute: String, value: Any, at point: CGPoint, textRange: NSRange) {
    guard let url = value as? URL else { return }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

For link detection you need to use external library. 
I'd recommend https://github.com/twitter/twitter-text
You can install it with cocoapods.

Then you need to convert TwitterTextEntity* to NSTextCheckingResult*.

You can use this category of NSString:

```
- (NSArray <NSTextCheckingResult *>*)textCheckingResultsForURLs {
    NSArray *twitterEntitiesArray = [TwitterText URLsInText:self];
    NSMutableArray *textCheckingResultsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[twitterEntitiesArray count]];

    for (TwitterTextEntity *twitterTextEntity in twitterEntitiesArray) {
        NSString *textCheckingResultUTF8 = [[self substringWithRange:twitterTextEntity.range] stringPercentEncode];

        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", textCheckingResultUTF8]];

        NSTextCheckingResult *result = [NSTextCheckingResult linkCheckingResultWithRange:twitterTextEntity.range URL:url];
        [textCheckingResultsArray addObject:result];
    }

    return textCheckingResultsArray;
}
```

Use it like this:

```
NSArray *links = [yourString textCheckingResultsForURLs];
```

Then you need to add calculated ranges to NSMutableAttributedString like this:

```
for (NSTextCheckingResult *textCheckingResult in links) {

        NSMutableDictionary *linkAttributes = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor]}];

        linkAttributes[@"TextLinkAttributeNameURL"] = [NSURL URLWithString:textCheckingResult.URL.absoluteString];

        [string addAttributes:linkAttributes range:textCheckingResult.range];
    }
```

Then you need to configure ASTextNode node to highlight specific ranges. So in parent node add:

```
_textLabelNode.delegate = self;
_textLabelNode.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
_textLabelNode.linkAttributeNames = @[@"TextLinkAttributeNameURL"];
```

+

```
- (void)didLoad {
    // For text node
    self.layer.as_allowsHighlightDrawing = YES;

    [super didLoad];
}

#pragma mark - ASTextNodeDelegate

- (BOOL)textNode:(ASTextNode *)richTextNode shouldHighlightLinkAttribute:(NSString *)attribute value:(id)value atPoint:(CGPoint)point {
    return YES;
}

- (void)textNode:(ASTextNode *)richTextNode tappedLinkAttribute:(NSString *)attribute value:(NSURL *)URL atPoint:(CGPoint)point textRange:(NSRange)textRange {
NSLog(@"TODO");
}
```

This works for me. Hope, didn't forget about anything.